# How to update the .NET CF into My WinCE device?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-ce, motorola, smart-device, smart-device-framework

I'm developping an application for Motorola MC3000 that use WinCE 5.0.

It seems that the machine is using the .NET CF 2.0, I just want to update it to .NET CF 3.5 but I don't know how to do it on the machine.

Any help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .NET Compact Framework installs side-by-side. You can simply copy the CAB file to the device, and run it. On your PC, you will find it at `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE\NETCFv35.wce.armv4.cab`.

If you need it to be reinstalled on a cold boot (user pressed 1 + 9 + power, or left the battery out for too long) you will need to write some code to reinstall it. See the documentation for [wceload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms933760.aspx) for silent installation, and see Motorola's [StartUpCtl](http://support.symbol.com/support/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=13481) for a way to control the order that things are run at start-up.

Some of Motorola's Windows Mobile devices had updates to allow the ROM version of .NET Compact Framework to be updated - for example the MC70 from 1.0 to 2.0 - but I'm not aware of any that had updates to replace it with 3.5.